# Get data from XSL Value-Of and put in <a> link

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get the value of Car in my XML file and use that value in  tag link. Or how do you get that value and use it.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
      <div style="background-color:#a61f2e;color:white;padding:4px; padding-left:1em;">
        <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 1.5em;">
           var #link = <xsl:value-of select="Car"/>
          /*How do I do this?*/
          <a id ="#link "> </a>
        </span>
      </div>

    </xsl:for-each>     
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) for that:

```
<xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
  <div style="background-color:#a61f2e;color:white;padding:4px; padding-left:1em;">
    <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 1.5em;">
      <a name ="{Car}"></a>
    </span>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You can also do it with an `<xsl:attribute>`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
  <div style="background-color:#a61f2e;color:white;padding:4px; padding-left:1em;">
    <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 1.5em;">
      <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="Car"/></xsl:attribute>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I was assuming an `<a name=""></a>` anchor. But you could do the same with an `<a href="">` hyperlink:

```
<a href="#{Car}">link</a>
```

or ID:

```
<span id="{Car}">object</a>
```

Comment: Thanks man that work. Just to let you know <a id=""></a> is HTML5 official way to use anchors now.